# FTP upload via PHP form

Tags: php, ftp

I want to upload a file via FTP upload in a form.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_file.php" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
      Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP file:

```
<?php

$ftp_server = "xxx";
$ftp_username   = "xxx";
$ftp_password   =  "xxx";

// setup of connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("could not connect to $ftp_server");

// login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_password))
{
  echo "conectd as $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
}
else
{
  echo "could not connect as $ftp_username\n";
}

$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$remote_file_path = "/home/www/lifestyle69/import/".$file;
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $file, FTP_ASCII);
ftp_close($conn_id);
echo "\n\nconnection closed";

?>
```

The FTP connection connects successfully but the file is nowhere.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you have `<input name="uploadedfile" type="file" />`:

```
$file = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; // wrong
$file = $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]; // right
```

Because you need the filename of the temporary copy stored by PHP, which exists on the server:

```
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $file, FTP_ASCII); // wrong
ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file_path, $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"],
        FTP_ASCII); // right
```

Refer to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for more information about $_FILES.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the folder you are uploading to has the correct permissions? Try chmoding it to 777 and see if that works.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Never suggest "try chmoding to 777" without a disclaimer "do this just for testing. Revert it back to safer permissions once you found what the problem is".

Comment: @mmalmeida I wonder about that. aren't permissions on the server behind a passworded ftp connection anyway? even if I have a 777 folder on my ftp host, it can't be written from internet, you have to be logged in to the server.

Comment: Felix, setting file permissions to 777 will allow anyone to read, write, or execute that file. No FTP access is required, you can access it through http.

Answer (score 1):

The file is stored on server with temporary name, so when you try uploading `$_FILES['file']['name']`, it fails, because file with such name does not exist. Instead you should call `ftp_put()` with `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`

It's explained a little better [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)