# HTML file input to FTP upload via PHP

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I have a standard HTML form, including a file input, allowing users of a web application to upload files (pictures, documents or videos).

It technically works, except when it comes with a large file...
I have a personal dedicated server on which I can change the PHP configuration to handle larger files ;
But this is not a reliable solution as my client has a shared hosting.

I know HTTP has different limits and is definitely not the best protocol to handle files.

So my objective is to **avoid HTTP upload**.

I was wondering if there is any way to rely on FTP to upload the selected file.

Any solution to upload files through FTP, directly from client's browser ?

EDIT :

- I've read some solutions about Java applets, however this is not
  really something I can, or even want to, provide.
- And as the files are **confidential**, using a third-party service is
  not possible neither.

Comment: you could use a third party file host

Comment: Technically, I totally could ! Except the files I am talking about are confidential, unfortunately...

Comment: if the files are confidential, then they shouldn't be ftp'd in the clear. you should sftp or scp instead... or even an https-based file upload.

Comment: Oh, yeah, thanks for the precision but obviousy, it will be over SSL, I'm just trying to figure out if HTML to FTPS is possible, but apparently not. Yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FTP upload via PHP form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280688/ftp-upload-via-php-form)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate of this thread. I am not talking about a PHP file handling HTTP-based upload files to THEN upload it via FTP. I am looking for a direct FTP-based upload, which does not exists yet.